# Catboost how to save model to python memory object and not disk

Tags: catboost

We like to use Catboost in an environment where we dont have permission to save data todisk. We found: https://github.com/catboost/tutorials/blob/master/model_analysis/model_export_as_json_tutorial.ipynb

Is there a way to pipe the model into an im memory python JSON object without saving to disk?

Answer (score 1):

Although it won't be a JSON, you can use the protected method `_serialize_model` on the `CatBoostClassifier` to get the model blob. For loading it use `CatBoostClassifier.load_model(blob=serialized_model)`.